# Updating UI of TicTacToe in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, networking, javafx-8

Here, I have a code below which I collected from the Internet for understanding TicTacToe game's code in java. I understand how the code is written along with its logics. It is played in a single window where two users are differentiated based on the button of the mouse clicked. Now I want to make a similar game which could be played over a network built with a server and a client.

**TicTacToe.java**

```
package sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    private boolean playable = true;
    private boolean turnX = true;
    private Tile[][] board = new Tile[3][3];
    private List<Combo> combos = new ArrayList<>();

    private Pane root = new Pane();

    private Parent createContent() {
        root.setPrefSize(600, 600);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                Tile tile = new Tile(); //each tile is a rectangular block
                tile.setTranslateX(j * 200);
                tile.setTranslateY(i * 200);

                root.getChildren().add(tile);

                board[j][i] = tile;
            }
        }

        // horizontal
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            combos.add(new Combo(board[0][y], board[1][y], board[2][y]));
        }

        // vertical
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            combos.add(new Combo(board[x][0], board[x][1], board[x][2]));
        }

        // diagonals
        combos.add(new Combo(board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]));
        combos.add(new Combo(board[2][0], board[1][1], board[0][2]));

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void checkState() {
        for (Combo combo : combos) {
            if (combo.isComplete()) {
                playable = false;
                playWinAnimation(combo);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void playWinAnimation(Combo combo) {
        Line line = new Line();
        line.setStartX(combo.tiles[0].getCenterX());
        line.setStartY(combo.tiles[0].getCenterY());
        line.setEndX(combo.tiles[0].getCenterX());
        line.setEndY(combo.tiles[0].getCenterY());

        root.getChildren().add(line);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                new KeyValue(line.endXProperty(), combo.tiles[2].getCenterX()),
                new KeyValue(line.endYProperty(), combo.tiles[2].getCenterY())));
        timeline.play();
    }

    private class Combo {
        private Tile[] tiles;
        public Combo(Tile... tiles) {
            this.tiles = tiles;
        }

        public boolean isComplete() {
            if (tiles[0].getValue().isEmpty())
                return false;

            return tiles[0].getValue().equals(tiles[1].getValue())
                    && tiles[0].getValue().equals(tiles[2].getValue());
        }
    }

    private class Tile extends StackPane {
        private Text text = new Text();
        private boolean clicked = false;;

        public Tile() {
            Rectangle border = new Rectangle(200, 200);
            border.setFill(null);
            border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

            text.setFont(Font.font(72));

            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            getChildren().addAll(border, text);

            setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                if (!playable || clicked)
                    return;

                if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    if (!turnX)
                        return;

                    if(!clicked){
                        drawX();
                        turnX = false;
                        clicked = true;
                        checkState();
                    }
                }
                else if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                    if (turnX)
                        return;

                    if(!clicked){
                        drawO();
                        turnX = true;
                        clicked = true;
                        checkState();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public double getCenterX() {
            return getTranslateX() + 100;
        }

        public double getCenterY() {
            return getTranslateY() + 100;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return text.getText();
        }

        private void drawX() {
            text.setText("X");
        }

        private void drawO() {
            text.setText("O");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I want to build the server and client in different files. The *server.java* will contain server sockets, input-output streams, and accept connections from a socket. I have no problem with that. Similarly, the *client.java* will also have sockets and necessary streams. Both the server file and the client file will also have the *TicTacToe.java*. I can set up the code up to this point.

**My problem:**

I cannot update the UI over the socket network. How can I do it? I've watched few codes on Platform.runLater() but do not understand them well. I wanted insight.

It would be very helpful for me if someone could give me a direction on how to write a code for this and implementing what I want so that I can solve my problem.

Thanks ...

Comment: You have many choices for how to transfer the data. Probably currently the most industry-standard would be to write a simple class that encapsulates the data you want to transfer, and then use a Java-JSON library, such as Jackson, to convert instances of the class to JSON format to send it, and convert them back when you receive it. You could also do the same with XML, or just define your own string representation of the data and parse it with your own code. There are plenty of examples, on this site and elsewhere, of the threading you ask about. Overall, this question is too vague/broad.

Comment: @James_D if you could...please give me some links. As I've already told , in many posts , the topic I want to know is briefly told and as a newbie, I just want a structure which I can in future manipulate myself and use accordingly. As you see , I just want to know how I could update the grid in both server an client . I think I've clearly mentioned what I want to know(update UI). As a beginner , understanding from texts without code has been rough for me in javafx. Any code guiding me is appreciable ...

Comment: I say the question is too vague/broad because it's not a specific programming question: it's "here are a couple of topics I want to learn about" (at best). This doesn't lend itself to a clear, specific answer. You are presumably just as capable as I am of googling, e.g. "Java Jackson Tutorial" or "JavaFX Threading Example".

Comment: @James_D well...I've searched about "updating UI in socket programming" but I don't see a link providing me with a simple example where I pass any object(text area,media view,grid) via socket and update it. I'm at a loss. And I just wanted to know how I could write a code to update the window for this game. If possible, I could use this idea in other cases too. And can't I do without java-jackson? My syllabus only revolves around basic Java,javafx. Thanks

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @James_D no, I've collected this from the web . I'm preparing myself in different projects on javafx so that I can learn things and use it for my future tasks.

Comment: @James_D I've updated my question.. hope it is understandable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done to use the Platform.RunLater function is create a background thread to receive packets from client/server. Then update the UI using the platform.runLater function...

```
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledPINGExecutorService;
private ScheduledFuture<?>       scheduledPINGCheck;

public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        primaryStage.setTitle("Title");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(getMainPage(primaryStage), 800, 1000));
        primaryStage.show();

scheduledPINGExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

Runnable checkPING = () -> {
            //check for new packet from client
            getData() <---- define this function depending on your networking setup
            Platform.runLater(() -> { //populate UI with new data  });
        };
scheduledPINGCheck = scheduledPINGExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(checkPING, 1, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }

'''
```

Comment: And how does it update the UI of both client and server ?

Comment: It will only update for one, so both the client and server will need to be listening for packets and update.

Comment: What should getData() do in my case? I mean what is its function ?

Comment: You should already have initialized communications, ie. created a socket. then the getData function will try to read the port to see if any data has come in. If you receive data from the client/server that contains an updated value for your graph, populate the graph during the runlater function.